# Declaring an interface with a new() signature, now when I use the interface as an object it gives me function properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So basically I'm currently typing up a type declaration file for typescript, everything is pretty good so far, however I'm having some trouble. I've set up a const to act as an Object or function depending on the way it's called, so I've got two interfaces and a const declaration. 
The first interface `File` uses a `new()` and `()` signature to change it's type if it's being called as a function or object, else it simply has a list of properties or functions you can call (kind of like a bunch of static class functions). Issue is the moment I add either of those signatures into the interface it starts returning propreties that are from the Function type. This is something I would prefer not happen if possible.

I've tried using things like, `Exclude<>` or `Pick<>` but to no luck.

```
declare const File: File;

interface File
{
    new(path?: String): FileObject;
    (path?: String): FileObject | FolderObject;   
}
```

I'd expect `File.[property]` to return nothing right now, instead it returns `File.[apply() | arguments | bind() |  call() | caller | length | prototype | toString()]`

PS. The `File().[property]` or `new File().[property]` work perfectly.

ANSWER:
For those of you who come to this, at the time of typing (2019/02/17) there is no way to exclude properties like that.

Comment: What's wrong with having the properties from `Function`? In JavaScript, every value that can be called or constructed must also be a function anyway.

Comment: There is no way to exclude those properties from a callable interface in typescript right now, there is a GitHub issue on it somewhere.. Also except for proxies I think, any callable js object will have the properties of `Function` anyway.

Comment: Oh, ok makes sense, thanks guys, I'll just put up with it for now (it was more of a cleanliness thing than an actual functionality thing).

Comment: The closest issue I can find in GitHub is [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575)... the suggested answer there keeps the keys but makes the values appear as an unusable type (like `null` or `never`) but they'd still show up in IntelliSense (which is what I assume is being discussed here).

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing a similar thing, but thanks for the heads up.